# Getting .scrollable is not a function Error

Tags: jquery, object, jquery-plugins, scroll, flowplayer

HI Guys.

While I am trying to scrolling my list, I am getting 
$(divElement).scrollable({ vertical: true, circular: true });  is not a function.

May be this because jquery.tools.min.js is conflicting with flowplayer-3.2.0.js.

I dont know how to come out of this problem, PLease help me.

Comment: are you importing jQuery **before** you import the plugin?

Comment: Yah, I am importing jquery befoer the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be, that  the function "scrollable" simply does not exist.

I currently discovered, that this function seems to be contained in some versions of jQuery ( i.e. jQuery 1.6.4.min ) , but not in all of them ( i.e. jQuery 1.7.0 ).

I found out by simply checking the jQuery script / library for the string "scrollable".

So it may not be contained in your version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does indeed conflict with flowplayer.
You need to add

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

immediately after including the jQuery library and update all your `$(...)` jQuery shortcuts to `jQuery(...)`.

See also [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. DO u think, this is the possible problem if I am getting this error of .scrollable is not a function??

Comment: only one way to find out, I guess. at least, given the details you've given above. :D

Comment: Yes it is most likely the problem, you're actually trying to call the .scrollable function on flowplayer, where it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

One of the stuff that isn't readily apparent with `jQuery.noConflict()` environments, is that while you're indeed letting go of the `$` variable, you can structure your code so that you use it for jQuery anyway.

If you're using `$(document).ready()` or `$(function() { })` (and you **should**), structure it like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // you can use $ for jQuery in here
});

// OR

jQuery(function($) {
    // here as well
});
```

Note the `$` parameter passed into the ready function.

Just in case you've already written tons of code and don't want to go back and rewrite every `$` to `jQuery`.